# Why is the color white darkened through glass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, light

So here are two pictures, the first one Has the outer eye object, which is just solid glass, and the inner eye, which is has a UV map of an eye. The second having just the inner eye. I took a screenshot of my whole screen so you could see I turned the outer eye visibility off on the top right.

[image]

Why does the glass darken the inner eye when the light is shining right at it? I could understand the outer eye is reflecting the background, but the light is shining directly at the left eye (as you can see in picture 2).
How do I fix the darkening while keeping the reflective property of an eye?

Comment: try adding a solidify modifier to your glass object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive testing, I have found that you need to add a glossy effect to the inner eye. For the outer eye, you need to have a mix shader with a glass and transparency shader connected to it.